# Bernoulli's principle for water in vertical pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, bernoulli-equation

I read [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/22016) that Bernoulli's equation can be written as:

$$h - h_f = \frac{V^2}{2g}$$

Where:

1. $h$ = water head
2. $h_f$ = head loss
3. $V$ = water velocity
4. $g$ = acceleration due to gravity

Is this formula correct, as it seems to ignore pressure head of water? If so, how would I refine it to include pressure head?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bernoulli's equation](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Easmits/Bicycle_web/Bernoulli.html)
states

$$P+\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2+\rho gh \tag1$$ is constant

The equation in your question seems to have been derived from that, with the $P$ terms equal.

If the outside pressure is equal, on the water at the top and bottom of the pipe, e.g. air pressure (ignoring changes in air pressure over a small distance), then the formula you had is ok (the pressure term is the pressure acting on the water, not the pressure that might be caused if the falling water were to hit a stationary object).

If the pressures are not equal it's best to make an equation with two sides using (1) and rearrange to get $h-h_f$